# Sorting sets of 4 ints in circular list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, circular-list

I am playing around with circular linked list to represent polynomials with it.

Here is what I have so far:

Class for parts of polynomial:

```
public class Wielomian {
int wsp;
int a;
int b;
int c;

public Wielomian(){
    wsp=0;
    a=-1;
    b=-1;
    c=-1;
}
public Wielomian(int wsp, int a, int b, int c){
    this.wsp = wsp;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

public String toString(){
    return wsp+"(x^"+a+")(y^"+b+")(z^"+c+")";
}
}
```

wsp is coefficient and a,b,c are exponents of x, y and z.

Node:

```
public class Node {

protected Object data;

protected Node link;

public Node() {
    link = null;
    data = 0;
}    

public Node(Object d,Node n) {
    data = d;
    link = n;
}

public void setLink(Node n) {
    link = n;
}

public void setData(Object d) {
    data = d;
}    


public Node getLink() {
    return link;
}    


public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

}
```

List:

```
class linkedList {

protected Node start ;
protected Node end ;
public int size ;


public linkedList() {
    start = null;
    end = null;
    size = 0;
}


public boolean isEmpty() {
    return start == null;
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}


public void insertAtStart(Object val) {

    Node nptr = new Node(val,null);
    nptr.setLink(start);
    if(start == null) {
        start = nptr;
        nptr.setLink(start);
        end = start;
    }
    else {
        end.setLink(nptr);
        start = nptr;
    }
    size++ ;
}

/* Function to insert element at end */

public void insertAtEnd(Object val) {

    Node nptr = new Node(val,null);
    nptr.setLink(start);
    if(start == null) {
        start = nptr;
        nptr.setLink(start);
        end = start;
    }
    else {
        end.setLink(nptr);
        end = nptr;
    }
    size++ ;
}

/* Function to insert element at position */

public void insertAtPos(Object val , int pos) {
    Node nptr = new Node(val,null);
    Node ptr = start;
    pos = pos - 1 ;
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == pos)
        {
            Node tmp = ptr.getLink() ;
            ptr.setLink( nptr );
            nptr.setLink(tmp);
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr.getLink();
    }
    size++ ;
}

/* Function to delete element at position */

public void deleteAtPos(int pos) {
    if (size == 1 && pos == 1) {
        start = null;
        end = null;
        size = 0;
        return ;
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        start = start.getLink();
        end.setLink(start);
        size--;
        return ;
    }
    if (pos == size) {
        Node s = start;
        Node t = start;
        while (s != end) {
            t = s;
            s = s.getLink();
        }
        end = t;
        end.setLink(start);
        size --;

        return;

    }
    Node ptr = start;
    pos = pos - 1 ;
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (i == pos) {
            Node tmp = ptr.getLink();
            tmp = tmp.getLink();
            ptr.setLink(tmp);
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr.getLink();
    }
    size-- ;
}


}
```

And I realised I need another add method that will and sort those parts of polynomial while adding - first by exponent of x, if 2 will have equal then by exponent of y and so on. 
The elements of list will be parts of polynomial and there also will be "head" which will be linked to the part with highest exponent at "x" and the last part of polynomial will be linked to this "head" making whole list circular. Head will have coefficient that equals 0 and exponats that equal -1 each. But I have no idea how to implement such method without ruining all the links etc. etc. I hope You guys can help me :)

I would also like to know best way to display my polynomial later. Will it be some kind of iteration through parts of polynomial and adding them to String until i reach "head"?

Comment: Your required behavior seems to be specific to your list elements being of class `Wielomian`.  In that case you should use that class directly, instead of pretending that your list can accommodate any `Object` whatever.  It can't.

Comment: Note also that sorting when you add elements is largely inconsistent with allowing elements to be added at user-specified positions (including adding specifically at the start or end).  You should choose one: either the list maintains its elements in order, or their order follows from the sequence of add and delete operations.  In the former case, the easiest thing to do is probably on each addition to search the (already sorted) list for the correct position, and insert the new node there (thus maintaining the sorted order).

Comment: I get Your point, changing "Object" to "Wielomian" won't be problem though. However I still don't know how to implement insert method that will determine where part of polynomial should be added or just how to sort it.

Comment: Those 3 "instertAt" methods are example methods that I, in fact, won't even need if I want to have those elements sorted. I just don't know how to sort elements of linked list

Comment: I already told you: you don't (need to) sort *after the fact*.  You need only choose the right position for each element added to the list, when it is added.  Supposing that the list starts sorted, which is trivially true for an empty list, it is then also sorted after each addition (via the as-yet hypothetical method that adds elements at their correct positions) and after each deletion.